# Google Text to Speech: word with minus character returns Timepoint second = 0

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech, ssml

**What I'm going to do**: I'd like to generate an mp3 file and timepoint information with Google Text to Speech.

**Context**: I'm using Java and the `google-cloud-texttospeech` library in version 2.4.0. `Timepoint` is `v1beta1.Timepoint`.

**Problem**: When I send the SSML string `<speak>Hallo <mark name="p1s0"/>Schmetterlings-Arten.</speak>` then the `time_seconds` in `Timepoint` in the response is `0`.

**What works**: When I exchange the German word "Schmetterlings-Arten" by "Schmetterlingsarten", everything is OK and the `time_seconds` in `Timepoint` in the response is 0.419, which is fine.

**Additional info**:
I'm using the voice for **"language_code" = "de-DE"**, **"name" = "de-DE-Wavenet-E"**, **"audio_encoding" = "MP3"** and **"enable_time_pointing" = "SSML_MARK"**.

**Question**:
Is there something special about a minus character in a word? Do I have to escape it somehow (and if so: how)?

**What I tried**: I tried some other names for that mark, added some spaces, added some other tags (e.g. START mark, END mark, some breaks, ...), tried to escape the minus character with a backslash, .... Nothing of that changed the result.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, this is an expected behavior when using any **German** language from the [supported voices and languages of text-to-speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices). The team for [Cloud Text-to-Speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech) product is constantly making changes to try to improve issues like this.

Possible workaround for now is to pre-process your **input SSML** and remove the hyphen(-) by using `REGEX REPLACE` similar to below sample using java.

```java
String original_SSML = "<speak>Hallo <mark name='p1s0'/>Schmetterlings-Arten.</speak>";
String updated_SSML = original_SSML.replace("-", "");
```

And then pass the updated variable to the **text-to-speech's input SSML** of your **request body**.

In addition, you may also [file a bug](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) for this *specific issue on German language* and **star** it if you want to be notified regarding the filed bug.

Comment: Thank you, @scott-b. This approach feels a little uncertain to me because it could break the semantic of from-to-expressions like from "8 AM - 9 AM" to "8 AM  9 AM". And maybe the pronunciation is a little or completely different of words like "text-to-speech" and "texttospeech". An issue report is filed here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242209984